# Giving full permission on samba share (Amazon EC2)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, samba

I have two ubuntu ec2 servers - let's say ServerA and ServerB.
ServerA has a large EBS attached to it and it's shared via Samba. This EBS is mounted to ServerB on /var/www/static. If I create file from ServerB using the ubuntu user (which exists on both servers), the default permission is set as follows
`-rw-r--r--    1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 2012-05-16 09:21 test`

What I am trying to do is give full permission (777) to all files in this share whoever creates the file from whichever server.

My `fstab` looks like this

`//ServerA/static /var/www/static cifs credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smbclient,umask=000 0 0`

Comment: This is my samba configuration `#======================= Share Definitions =======================
[static]
comment = Static Content
browseable = yes
writable = yes
path = /var/www/static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[static]
   comment = Static Content
   browseable = yes
   writable = yes
   path = /var/www/static
   force create mode = 0777
```

In addition, you can use ACL to grant permissions for created items:

```
setfacl -m user:www-data:rwx,default:user:www-data:rwx,mask::rwx /var/www/static
getfacl /var/www/static
```

Look for `inherit acls`, `inherit permissions` etc. in the [smb.conf man page](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html).